# Nested foreach loop inside for loop duplicates data returned

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code and no matter what I have tried, I cannot get it to return only the data once.

```
<div class="container">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.First().NumberOfRows; i++)
    {
        <div class="row">
        @foreach (var columns in Model)
        {

                <div class="@columns.BootstrapColumns">
                    @columns.BodyText
                </div>

            }
        </div>
    }

</div>
```

I have tried putting a counter in the code moving the code around reading posts online but nothing works.

Am I missing something simple, the for loop works OK, but the foreach is causing the problem.

Move the foreach outside the for loop and it works Ok, but I need it to be inside the for loop.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Row 2 column 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Row 2 Column 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Row 2 Column 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Rows 3 column 1</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Row 2 column 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Row 2 Column 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Row 2 Column 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Rows 3 column 1</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>column 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Row 2 column 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Row 2 Column 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Row 2 Column 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Rows 3 column 1</p>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Camilo Terevinto IF I DO THAT I GET THE FOLLOWING WHICH IS NOT WHAT I'M AFTER

```
<div class="container">


<div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-3">
                 <p>column 1</p>
             </div>
         </div>
<div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-3">
                 <p>column 2</p>
             </div>
         </div>
<div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-3">
                 <p>column 3</p>
             </div>
         </div>
<div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-3">
                 <p>column 4</p>
             </div>
         </div>
<div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-4">
                 <p>Row 2 column 1</p>
             </div>
         </div>
<div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-4">
                 <p>Row 2 Column 2</p>
             </div>
         </div>
<div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-4">
                 <p>Row 2 Column 3</p>
             </div>
         </div>
<div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-12">
                 <p>Rows 3 column 1</p>
             </div>
         </div>


</div>
```

Hi user7396598 I'm trying to get the code to display the following:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">row 1 col1</div>
<div class="col-md-4">row 1 col2</div>
<div class="col-md-4">row 1 col3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">row 2 col1</div>
<div class="col-md-3">row 2 col2</div>
<div class="col-md-3">row 2 col3</div>
<div class="col-md-3">row 2 col4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">row 3 col1</div>
</div>
```

My for loop get the number of rows, the foreach loop is then supposed to get the columns and display in column in the row.

I cannot see any other way of doing this without 1st getting the number of rows with the for loop.

======================View Model====================

```
public class NestedContentViewModel
    {
        public NestedContentViewModel() { }

        public NestedContentViewModel(int numberOfRows, HtmlString bodyText, string image, string imageAlternativeText,string rowBackgroundColour, string bootstrapColumns, int numberOfColumns)
        {
            NumberOfRows            = numberOfRows;
            BodyText                = bodyText;
            Image                   = image;
            ImageAlternativeText    = imageAlternativeText;
            RowBackgroundColour     = rowBackgroundColour;
            BootstrapColumns        = bootstrapColumns;
            NumberOfColumns         = numberOfColumns;
        }

        public int NumberOfRows             { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfColumns          { get; set; }
        public string BootstrapColumns      { get; set; }
        public HtmlString BodyText          { get; set; }
        public string Image                 { get; set; }
        public string ImageAlternativeText  { get; set; }
        public string RowBackgroundColour   { get; set; }
    }
```

==================Controller================

```
foreach (var rows in nestedContentRows)
                    {
                        int numberOfBootstrapColumns = rows.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("columns").Count();
                        string bootstrapColumn = "";

                        switch (numberOfBootstrapColumns)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                bootstrapColumn = "col-md-12";
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                bootstrapColumn = "col-md-6";
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                bootstrapColumn = "col-md-4";
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                bootstrapColumn = "col-md-3";
                                break;
                            default:
                                bootstrapColumn = "col-md-12";
                                break;
                        }

                        foreach (var columns in rows.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("columns"))
                        {
                            HtmlString bodyText = columns.HasValue("bodyText")? columns.GetPropertyValue<HtmlString>("bodyText"): new HtmlString(string.Empty);
                            model.Add(new NestedContentViewModel(numberOfRows: countNumberOfRows,bodyText: bodyText, image: null, imageAlternativeText: null,rowBackgroundColour: "cssTurquoiseBlue", bootstrapColumns: bootstrapColumn, numberOfColumns: numberOfBootstrapColumns));
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You are looping the entire Model inside each iteration, what do you expect to happen but duplication? Remove the `@for` entirely

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto i have updated the code to your suggestion and it does not work, I had already tried that.

Comment: What does your Model consist of?  What is the desired output?

Comment: @user7396598 i have replied to your question

Comment: please post the view Model.  I think you are looping through the wrong object(s).

Comment: @user7396598 I have added view model and controller

Comment: In this line @foreach (var columns in Model) - is Model made up of a List<NestedContentViewModel>  ???

Comment: @user7396598 yes, that my model

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is in your Model structure.  And naming conventions, your names cause all manner of confusion.  Currently your model is a list of your NestedContentViewModel objects, and you are making a new NestedContentViewModel for each BodyText value.

Your BodyText should actually be a collection within each NestedContentViewModel.  This would "relate" your BodyText(column info) to a NestedContentViewModel(row).  Also, move rowNumber out of NestedContentViewModel and put it in the parent that contains a List

Then your loops would look like this:

```
@foreach (var row in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
    @foreach (var column in row.ColumnCollection)
    {
            <div class="@row.BootstrapColumns">
                @column.BodyText
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

I hope this sets you in the right direction.  If you need help restructuring the models you may want to edit and clean up the question text.

Comment: thanks, that code was getting me confused to start, I'm even more confused now :(